# Pulling quantiative and qualitative out of varying strings of text

Tags: excel, vba, data-cleaning, keyword

I am trying to standardize a dataset in Excel. I'm looking to pull volumes (in gallons, for example) for certain lubricants as well as the name of the lubricant, when possible. The string that holds this information differs on each line because it is manually scribed into an maintenance management tool on the front end. The data is very messy and I'm unsure of the best way to leverage LookUp, VBA, or something else in Excel to pull consistent keywords out of the strings.

For example, here is a chunk of the data:
[4 cells of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v2XA.png)

I'm looking to pull out:
15W-40 @ 250 gallons,
Diesel Exhaust Fluid @ 2.5 gallons (30 units)
so on and so forth

Comment: your best bet would be to go to where ever the data is coming from and seeing if it can be standardized / cleaned up at that layer.  In those 4 lines, there is no consistent pattern.  How did you know lines 3 and 4 go together?

Comment: Trying to harmonize disparate text is a nightmare when it's completely disorganized like your example, agree with sous2817 to ask for it to be changed / organized at the source.